# Javascript function allocation inside a loop garbage creation

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Simple question but I haven't found an answer that I'm 100% sure of yet. Consider this code:

Version 1:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
function doStuff(obj) {
    //do nothing
}
function test() {
    a.forEach(doStuff);
}
setInterval(test, 1000/60);
```

Version 2:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
function test() {
    a.forEach(function(obj) {
        //do nothing
    });
}
setInterval(test, 1000/60);
```

Version 1 allocates 2 functions and then does not ever allocate anything else.

Does Version 2 allocate a new function every time test() is called? My understanding is that the anonymous function inside the forEach in version 2 gets created **each time** test() is called but, once the call to test() ends, has no more references to it and can be garbage collected. Thus, if version 2 was left to run for a long time, the garbage collector would have to be active in cleaning up the garbage objects version 2 created. Am I right?

Comment: Did you really mean to call test sixty thousand times per second? Because the browser won't respect that  request.

Comment: Yes, Version 2 does instantiate a new function object every time `test` is called, but it might be able to allocate it on the stack without any (heap) garbage collection ever needing to run.

Comment: ES3 allowed the 2nd function to be recycled, i can't imagine that later cores wouldn't also optimize like that, re-using all but the activation part of the function.

Comment: @JanDvorak my bad meant to be 60 / second.

Answer (score 0):

We can test this by using a function that saves its argument, and then test whether they're equal.

```js
var saved = [];

function saveIt(fun) {
  saved.push(fun);
}

function test() {
  saveIt(function(obj) {
    // do nothing
  });
}

test();
test();
console.log(saved[0] === saved[1]);
```

When I run this in Chrome, it logs `false`, so the two functions are indeed different.

However, the difference might not be in the code part of the function, but in the context of the closures. A decent compiler should be able to tell that every call to this uses the same code for the anonymous function, and extract that into a common object that all the closures refer to.

An even smarter compiler should notice that this function never refers to any free variables, so it doesn't need to use the lexical context. So every use of it should be equivalent and it can be reused all the time. But apparently the Chrome compiler isn't that clever.

Comment: One does not simply trust different web browsers to make the same arbitrary choices ;-)

Comment: "*But apparently the Chrome compiler isn't that clever.*" - How do you know? The point is that this optimisation is only possible when it is not observable.

Comment: Are you suggesting that when it compiles `test()` it checks whether `saveIt()` does something with the function that would make the difference visible, and then omits the optimization?

Comment: So either it's not clever enough, or it's *too* clever.

Comment: I guess if you really want to know, you should use something like the original code in the question, and then check the memory graph in Developer Tools. But it may take a while to notice, since the function is so small that the memory allocations will be hard to see.